# how to initialize checkbox state before the xib file is loaded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

a newbie question:
basically, 
I created a cocoa application, when it starts, a popup windows shows up , 2 checkboxes, you can choose any one or none of them, then click Yes or No button to finish. In my project I have :

AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m  -- this one is generated once the project is created by Xcode.

start.h       and start.m     -- once Yes or No button is clicked , this one is called to do something.

Now, I need to modify this to :

1st , check if some file exists,

if file exists,   checkbox is enabled, means users can check them. 
  if no file,       checkbox is disabled, means gray out , users can't check them.

If I put `[checkbox1 setEnabled: NO]` in start.m , checkbox1's state only change when I click on Yes or No button.

So question is where should I and how can I initialize the checkbox states before the window pops up. Thanks a lot.

appdelegate.h:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


 @interface UninstallAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     NSWindow *window;

 }

 @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

 @end
```

appdelegate.m:

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"


 @implementation AppDelegate

 @synthesize window;


 - (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {

    return YES;
 }

 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

     NSLog(@"app finish launching is called");
     [window center];
 }

 @end
```

start.h:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 @interface start : NSWindowController {
     IBOutlet id yesbutton;
     IBOutlet id nobutton;

     IBOutlet NSButton *checkBoxEDK;
     IBOutlet NSButton *checkBoxSDL;
 }



 - (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
 - (IBAction)quit:(id)sender;


 @end
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `appdelegate.h` class and `start.h` class declarations? An instance of the `appdelegate` is likely included in the nib(xib) file, but how is the instance of `start` created? (Is there also an instance of it in the nib file, or is the `appdelegate` creating it, or?)

Comment: Thank for your reply. I will update the code in my question.